# Can I append my component to a div's existing content in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

When we use `ReactDOM.render(<Component/>,document.getElementById("container"));` The component gets rendered to the element mentioned. What if the div here already has some existing content inside it? Can React append the rendered component to it? e.g:

HTML:

```
<div id = "container">Hello, React!</div>
```

JSX:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return(
                    <p>Hello to you too!</p>
                )
            }
        })
        ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: The best way would be to try it out yourself and see if can still see 'hello ,React' before the component renders. But best practices suggest that its better the render on an empty element.

Comment: I can see 'Hello, React!' before. But this is because I'm compiling JSX online using browser.min.js which takes time to load.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell, this is the only way to do what you're asking (as I was trying to do the same thing):

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    const id = Math.random() //or some such identifier 
    const d = document.createElement("div")
    d.id = id
    divs[i].appendChild(d)
    ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent/>, document.getElementById(id))
}
```

If anyone knows of a cleaner/better way to append the `react` component to the existing `<div>` without first attaching the new empty `<div>`, please chime in!

Answer (score 1):

When you render a react component in a div, its contents are being replaced by the contents of the component you created.

```
    <script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<div class = 'outer-container'>
<p>
I can see this hello.
</p>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
    <p>
      Hello React
    </p>
</div>

</div>
```

JSX

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="Button">
        <span className="left" onClick={function() {alert("left")}}>Left</span>
        <span className="right" onClick={function() {alert("right")}}>Right</span>
        <span className="middle" onClick={function() {alert("middle")}}>Middle</span>
      </div>
    );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

You can see a fiddle here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltdc8qpr/21/)

Comment: My question is, Is there a way to do it in the same div? Not wrapping it inside another.

Comment: I that case you need to render the other data in the div also in the same react component.

Comment: this is correct, but it causes to me a `Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment` error if I do not in development environment...

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some wrap container for the stuff that you don't want to be overridden. It's should be something like:

```
<div id='wrapper-container'>
   <p>Hello, React! Content before</p>
   <div id='container'></div>
   <p>Content after</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keeping existing content is possible using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Considering the name you may already guess that this is it not the most suggested way, but it works:

HTML:

```
<div id = "container">Hello, React!</div>
```

JS:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>{this.props.children}<p>Hello to you too!</p></div>
    )
  }
})
var c = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Component, {}, <div className="children"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: c.innerHTML }}></div>), c);
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3hdwp0m/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do it is to create another div element, then append it to the container, then get the Element id and render the component inside of it. That means each render will have it's own parents stand inside the container div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other answers, **React 18** warns that you need to use createRoot instead.

You can fix it by replacing ReactDom.render with this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

createRoot(document.getElementById("container")).render( <Component/>)
```